# Why is my code opening another file and handling error exceptions?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I am trying to run a file (asana_get_user.py) in C:\Users\WilsonNg\Documents\Internship via python.

However, when I run it, I get an attribute error:

**error message**

[image]

However, there is another exception error happening after this code is finished for some reason:

**exception error**

[image]

So it opened another file (email.py) within the same folder and created an exception error.

Any idea on why it referenced my email.py file?

asana_get_user.py

```
import asana

# replace with your personal access token. 
personal_access_token = '0/2c...'

# Construct an Asana client
client = asana.Client.access_token(personal_access_token)
# Set things up to send the name of this script to us to show that you succeeded! This is optional.
client.options['client_name'] = "hello_world_python"

# Get your user info
me = client.users.me()

# Print out your information
print ("Hello world! " + "My name is " + me['name'] + " and I my primary Asana workspace is " + me['workspaces'][0]['name'] + ".")
```

email.py

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}

def send_message(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print ('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
  except (errors.HttpError, error):
    print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)


subject = "This is a test subject"
message = "This is a test content"
sent_to = "test@test.com"
sender = "test@test.com"

sending_msg = create_message(sender,sent_to,subject,message)

send_message()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put a check in `email.py` as `if __name__ == '__main__':` before `subject = "This is a test subject"`.

`email.py` is being run as the `import asana` is called.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    subject = "This is a test subject"
    message = "This is a test content"
    sent_to = "test@test.com"
    sender = "test@test.com"

    sending_msg = create_message(sender,sent_to,subject,message)

    send_message()
```

Read about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-if-__name__-__main__-do/).